# PHP json_encode multidimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've used php's `json_encode()` function many times, but for some reason I can't seem to find the problem here...

Note: I've removed error checking for clarity purposes.

//PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'global/query.php';
$sql = "SELECT sfl,station,latitude,longitude,address,city FROM maps";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $trows[] = $result;
}
echo json_encode($trows);
?>
```

I'm using AJAX and am just `console.log()`-ing the output to print the response like so...

//JS

```
var callback = {
    "projects": function(e){
        console.log(e.target.response);
    }
};
```

In the console it prints a blank line with none of the data...

---

Now if I `var_dump` the `$trows` the output in the console will print the data so I know my sql statement works just fine...

//PHP

```
var_dump($trows);
```

//CONSOLE

```
array(522) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sfl"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["station"]=>
    string(26) "COMPRESSOR STATION"
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(4) "-115"
    ["address"]=>
    string(10) "Unnamed Rd"
    ["city"]=>
    string(9) "blah"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sfl"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["station"]=>
    string(17) "STA TERMINAL"
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(4) "-101"
    ["address"]=>
    string(11) "15 Ranch Dr"
    ["city"]=>
    string(8) "Blah Blah"
  },
```

**Questions:** Why isn't my php's json_encode function working? I've used this exact code before and the output was fine.

Comment: Did you test your page by simply opening it in a browser? Do you get the expected output? If yes: problem in your AJAX code, if not: What exactly are you receiving?

Comment: You're using the console already; why not look in the Net tab of the dev tools to see what the actual http response looks like?

Comment: @ccKep Yea if I var_dump the `$trows` variable it will dump the data to the console, if I use `json_encode` it prints blank line

Comment: @Simba Yea I've looked at that as well it and it's blank response.

Comment: You gave a lot of info but still not helpful. Are you sure that you use `utf-8` as encoding? I saw a lot of problem related to encoding. Also check out that you cleaned up your output buffer.

Comment: I notice you have an `Array` of 522 items. Could you try it with a smaller subset of known working data (possibly even one item). That way you can test if there might be outlying issues in the bigger `Array`.

Comment: @MuntashirAkon yea it was encoding error, thanks for your help!

Comment: @VincentWilkie yea I thought that might of been it at first, but I did test that before and it wasn't related, thanks for your input though!

Comment: @JordanDavis You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and add:

```
 header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Before you echo your JSON encoded result.

**EDIT:**

If the encoding doesn't work try the following:

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $trows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $result);
}
```

Comment: You nailed it, it was encoding error and the `array_map()` fixed it!

Comment: Cheers mate, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

I would see what PHP tells you:

Change

```
echo json_encode($trows);
```

to

```
$json = json_encode($trows);
$error = json_last_error();
if ($error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo json_last_error_msg();
} else {
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: I'll throw that in there in try it 1 sec

Comment: Ok yea it finally outputted encoding error, thank you for your help +1